# Dynamically Adding event handlers to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm looking for help with an app I'm building. I've an xml file being read into an app. This XML is of the following structure:

```
 `<Tabs>
  <Tab>
    <Search name="ListSearch" Title="SearchHeader">
      <Label Name="lblSchema"></Label>
      <ComboBox Name="comboxSchema" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True" ItemSource="{Binding AvailableSchema}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSchema}" />
      <ComboBox Name="comboxList" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True" ItemSource="{Binding AvailableList}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedList}" />
      <Label Name="lblCriteria"></Label>
      <ComboBox Name="comboxFields" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True" ItemSource="{Binding AvailableFields}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedField}" />
      <ComboBox Name="comboxOperator" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True" ItemSource="{Binding Operations}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOperator}" />
      <TextBox Name="txtBoxInputValue" Visibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True" Text="{Binding InputValue}" />
      <CustomControl type="DatePicker"></CustomControl>
      <Button Name="btnAddQueryLine" Content="{Binding TextOnAddQueryButton}" Command="{Binding CamlAddQueryLine}" Action="Publish"></Button>
      <Button Name="btnPasteQueryLine" Content="{Binding TextOnPasteQueryButton}" Command="{Binding CamlPasteQueryLine}" Action="Preview"></Button>
      <Button Name="btnRemoveQueryLine" Content="{Binding TextOnRemoveQueryButton}" Command="{Binding CamlRemoveQueryLine}" Action="UnPublish"></Button>
      <Button Name="btnClearQuery" Content="{Binding TextOnClearQueryButton}" Command="{Binding CamlClearQuery}" Action="UnPreview"></Button>
      <Button Name="btnCamlSearch" Content="{Binding TextOnSearchQueryButton}" Command="{Binding CamlSearch}" Action="Meh"></Button>
      <Button Name="btnCloseSearch" Content="{Binding TextOnCloseQueryButton}" Command="{Binding CloseSearch}" Action="NewMeh"></Button>
    </Search>
  </Tab>

  </Tabs>`
```

So I read in the xml, and use methods like this to add buttons etc to the ribbon:

```
private void AddButtonToGroup(string header,RibbonGroup group,string command,string action)
    {
         RibbonButton button = new RibbonButton();
         button.Label = header;
         button.Name = action;

         button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
         group.Items.Add(button);
    }
```

with the following event handler:

```
void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button clicked = (Button)sender;

        MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked!");
        MessageBox.Show("Performing Action:" + clicked.Name);

    }.
```

The problem I have, is that this isn't the requirement- the event handler is hard coded. Is there any way to create event handlers dynamically? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which kind of actions will the users be able to assign to a button? You need to restrict this somehow. Creating code dynamically can be very complex.

Comment: Thats the problem. Potentially, the action could be run a search, delete something, open a pop-up, open a new tab, cancel a search, or quite a few other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a set of actions that the user will be able to do. Then assign a name to each one of them and implement the actions in code.

For example, the XML would be:

```
<Button Content="TextOnAddQueryButton" Command="CamlAddQueryLine"></Button>
```

In code, you would assign the event handler like this:

```
private void AddButtonToGroup(string header,RibbonGroup group,string command,string action)
{
     RibbonButton button = new RibbonButton();
     button.Tag = command;
     //...
}
```

And the handler for the button would be:

```
void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clicked = (Button)sender;

    switch (clicked.Tag)
    {
        case "CamlAddQueryLine":
            // Call action for CamlAddQueryLine
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could create a method that returns an [`Action<object, RoutedEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx):

```
private Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> MakeButtonClickHandler()
{
   return (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
      {
         // Put your code here, it will be called when
         // the button is clicked
      };
}
```

So `MakeButtonClickHandler` returns a new anonymous function each time it's called. Then assign it like this:

```
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MakeButtonClickHandler());
```

Another way of accomplishing the same thing is to do this inline, like so:

```
button.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        // Put your code here
    };
```

For some more information, take a look at [Anonymous Functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx).

Comment: Hey @Donut,I understand what you're doing here, but this still isn't dynamic, is it? the MakeButtonClickHandler is still a hardcoded method. I need to find a way to create the event handlers on-the-fly from something I put in the XML. Is this even possible?

Comment: @scarecrow198504 Can you give some specific examples of how you want it to work? I'm guessing your actions are based on the `command` and `action` parameters to the `AddToButtonGroup` method you posted. Is this correct, and how do you want these parameters to work?